# iOS: didDiscoverPeripheral not called in Background mode

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am Working on BLE project, everything works fine when the app in the foreground.It can discover and connect to the peripheral, all the call back method work perfectly.

But the problem is that, when the app in the background mode (I press home button). Only the  `centralManagerDidUpdateState`  delegate method get called.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
          [self.cbCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I use  `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil`  option, But when the app in the background, the  `didDiscoverPeripheral`  call back never called. I have edit my plist file with "bluetooth-central" option to support ble central role in background.

Any idea why  `didDiscoverPeripheral`  method not call when app in the background?

Comment: `didConnwctPeripheral` will get called in response to a `connect`, not a `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` .  Do you get a call to `didDiscoverPeripheral`?  Note that the duplicates option is ignored in the background and you will only get a single discovery event for each peripheral.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the `didDiscoverPeripheral` not called actually, I have edited my question. If the app in the foreground already start scanning the peripherals, When the app in the background, does the  `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` call back get called for the same peripheral? Does iOS ignore the duplicates when it found the peripheral in the foreground?

Comment: Correct, if a discovery notification for a given peripheral has already been delivered in the foreground or the background you will not receive any further discovery notifications for that peripheral in the background.

Comment: If I would like still receive `didDiscoverPeripheral` call back for the same peripheral in the background what should I do? Do I initial a new Central class to restart scanning? I actually want to reconnect the same peripheral when the app in the background. If the `didDiscoverPeripheral`  not called how could I reconnect. In the apple Bluetooth guide, I could use the  `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` to restore the peripheral. But I get null peripheral from  the `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` method.

Comment: If you want to connect, simply issue a connect. Once the peripheral comes back into range the connection will complete and you will get a call to `didConnectPeripheral`. Basically in `didDisconnectPeripheral` simply call connect with their peripheral object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paulw11 said are right, If your app find the peripherals in the foreground. It will not call the `didDiscoverPeripheral` for the same peripherals when it enters the background.

For more information about the iOS BLE Behavior in the background mode. You can check this answer 
[What exactly can CoreBluetooth applications do whilst in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896562/what-exactly-can-corebluetooth-applications-do-whilst-in-the-background/10096244#10096244)

Answer (score 3):

I was working on Estimote Nearable type beacons. After iOS10 SDK update, I encountered exception from `CBCentralManager` stating :

`<CBCentralManager:   0x17009e050> has provided a restore identifier but the delegate doesn't implement   the centralManager:willRestoreState: method`

To fix this, **Turn-On "Background Mode"**, in **Xcode -> Capabilities -> Background Mode**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Scan for `nil`( `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil`) services will not work in background. You must search for some specific service in background.

You have to set the `UUID` in `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:` method which Peripherals/BLE device is advertising.

Answer (score 1):

From Official Apple reference

> You can provide an array of CBUUID objects—representing service
>   UUIDs—in the serviceUUIDs parameter. When you do, the central manager
>   returns only peripherals that advertise the services you specify
>   (recommended). If the serviceUUIDs parameter is nil, all discovered
>   peripherals are returned regardless of their supported services (not
>   recommended). If the central manager is already scanning with
>   different parameters, the provided parameters replace them. When the
>   central manager object discovers a peripheral, it calls the
>   centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI: method of
>   its delegate object.
>
> Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are
>   allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must
>   explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the
>   serviceUUIDs parameter. The CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey
>   scan option is ignored while scanning in the background.

Here

**Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the serviceUUIDs parameter.**

So `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil` with nil it will not work in background , you need to specify list of UUIDS