# How to receive Core Bluetooth notification when iOS app is killed state

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

I am working on an iOS app that is related to the Core Bluetooth framework of Apple.

My App uses the BLE mechanism to detect peripheral iOS devices. When the app is in the foreground and the external device's bluetooth is in the range of the iPhone's Bluetooth than the app is notified and some kind of defined animation is played in the app.
I enabled the background service for the app using info plist like this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
</array>
```

When the app is not in background or suspended state (it should be killed state) then also we need notification from the external device to our iOS app.
Is this possible? If yes, then how can we achieve this mechanism?

Comment: Check this question and its answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578813/corebluetooth-and-ios-states.

Comment: Your answer doesn't demonstrate how it will work in killed state. We need to work on killed state and you said it is not possible.

Comment: _it's not possible_ - that's exactly the demonstration on how the app works in a killed state.

Comment: The only thing that helps you is Apple's "State Preservation and Reservation" for Bluetooth (https://www.google.se/search?q=state+preservation+and+restoration+bluetooth)

Comment: Yes, state preservation will relaunch your app if a relevant Bluetooth event occurs; this is a peripheral with a pending connection coming into range or a peripheral that matches a service scan comes into range

Comment: is there any some snip of code that explain "state preservation will relaunch your app if a relevant Bluetooth event occurs" @Paulw11

Comment: It is described in the CoreBluetooth programming guide and you can have a look at some sample code here: https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground